# What will __name__ be when python script run from crontab?

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

The question says it all. If I have a cronjob that runs a python script, what will the value of `__name__` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as if you run it directly from your shell. There is no difference between running it from your shell or from the crontab.